# How can i edit and reduce gcloud SQL instance size (ssd storage)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, instance, gcloud, google-cloud-sql, solid-state-drive

As "Auto storage increase is enabled" was enabled on my instance along with "general logs ". due to which my instance crossed the storage of 5TB .but after clearing logs .space required by DBS is far lesser than the actual size of the instance.

How can i edit the size of instance to 2tb from 5 TB

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You basically [can't](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/instance-settings#storage-capacity-2ndgen).

You can always [export your data](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/exporting#mysqldump), and [import it](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/importing)  to a new Cloud SQL instance with the right size.

EDIT:

There is a Feature Request in the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/63069754), but right now what I mentioned above is the only way to go.

Comment: I have multiple Dbs under one instance and the above-mentioned process will take time and effort

Comment: @RohitSureka There is a Feature Request in Google's Public Issue Tracker, but right now there is no other way. Check my edit for the link to the FR.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to **reduce Instance size(Storage capacity)** for all [**PostgreSQL**](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/instance-settings#storage-capacity-2ndgen), [**MySQL**](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/instance-settings#storage-capacity-2ndgen) and [**SQL Server**](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/instance-settings#storage-capacity-2ndgen) on Cloud SQL. Only increasing Instance size is possible.

But, if you really want to **reduce Instance size** from **5 TB** to **2 TB** on **Cloud SQL**, you can **export the data from the existing instance** :

[image]

And **import the data into a new instance** which you newly created with **the Instance size 2 TB**. This way, you can **reduce Instance size** from **5 TB** to **2 TB** on **Cloud SQL**:

[image]